# When is right time to load data in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I need load data from database in Prism application and I don't know when. 
Should I load data in constructor of view model ?
When is right time to load data in Prism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I load data in constructor of view model ?

If you use the `ViewModelLocator` avoid loading data in the constructor to not block the ui. If you create the view model yourself (i.e. somewhere in a background task), nothing's wrong with loading data in the constructor. In fact, I'd prefer that because you always have an initialized instance.

> When is right time to load data in Prism ?

The above being said, the best bet is to implement `INavigationAware` and load your data in `OnNavigatedTo` (asynchronously, of course).

Comment: What if we are in the Shell's ViewModel, wich is not Navigated but directly loaded by Prism initialization?

Comment: The shell doesn't have this problem: it simply _must_ load fast, because it's the first thing the user sees and noone wants to double click on a shortcut and then have the machine (seemingly) sitting idly. The user expects an immediate reaction... create the shell to show something to the user, then navigate somewhere.

Comment: Should I use IRegionManager's RegisterViewWithRegion or RequestNavigate? I also read of _navigationService.NavigateAsync somewhere but I can't find a working sample.

Comment: I'd navigate in `OnInitialized`, I guess, and probably even show a splash screen while the modules load.